# remove from List using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

So, I have a List of objects of class `A` that contains a `List` of objects of class `B`

```
class A 
{
  ...
  List<B> bs;
}
```

and I have lists:

```
List<A> mainList;
List<B> listForRemoval;
```

How can I, using Linq, "clean" mainList, by removing all objects from bs (for every A in mainList) that exists in listForRemoval?

I hope I didn't confuse you with this question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

linq itself is probably not a great fit, but you can use some of it's extension methods. Linq typically is mostly for selection, not processing.

```
mainList.ForEach(x=>x.bs = x.bs.Where(y=>!listForRemoval.Contains(y)).ToList());
```

Comment: This will create many new instances of lists that are overrided.

Comment: @VMAtm - Yeah I would prefer a RemoveAll when dealing with List objects too because you don't know if there are lingering references out there. I was just showing using some of the linq extension methods. I was really just treating as if you were simply dealing with any "IEnumberable".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, as the other answers have shown. I would, however, choose the following solution which does not use LINQ at all:

```
foreach (var a in mainList) {
    a.bs.RemoveAll(b => listForRemoval.Contains(b));
}
```

Advantages:

- It's easier to read and understand.
- It's not longer than the LINQ-based solutions---in fact, it's *shorter* than the accepted, LINQ-based answer.
- It *removes* the elements from bs rather than assigning a *new list* to bs. This might yield better performance and/or be necessary if the list is used in other places as well.

Comment: I would suggest even when using the "RemoveAll" method there is no reason not to use the the "ForEach" method of the parent List like VMAtm did.

Comment: @Xenophile: Personally, I consider `foreach (var x in list) ...` to be easier to read than `list.ForEach(x => ...)` (especially if additional levels of nested parenthesis follow), but that might be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var list in mainList) {
    list.bs = list.bs.Where(b => !listForRemoval.Contains(b)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You need a "!" infront of contains.. you are doing the opposite of what he wanted with the sublist if I read that right.

Comment: @Xenophile - Oops.  Thanks for the catch.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
mainList.ForEach(a => a.bs.RemoveAll(b => listForRemoval.Contains(b)));
```